Flutter integration test pauses indefinitly without error in docker compose
I have chrome driver and flutter integration tests setup in docker compose service.
When I run it - I dont see any error. But tests never complete. Terminal just pauses.
Docker compose yaml:
  start-chrome-driver:
    <<: *base
    tty: true
    container_name: start-chrome-driver
    command: >
      bash -c "/opt/chromedriver-linux64/chromedriver --port=4444 "

  run-integration-tests:
    <<: *base
    container_name: run-integration-tests
    depends_on:
      - start-chrome-driver
    command: >
      bash -c "chmod +x integration_test/run_all_tests.sh  
      && ./integration_test/run_all_tests.sh"

Terminal output:
ChromeDriver was started successfully.
integration_test/001_homepage_test.dart is being served at http://localhost:42789

It doesnt proceed. As soon as I click on the url shown above - I am able to see entire test run in a browser window.
But if I run chrome driver outside of compose service - on host machine .
And then I run integration tests through docker compose service - then it works.
Dart code homepage_test.dart
void main() {
  IntegrationTestWidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();

  group('homepage test', () {
    testWidgets('homepage', (tester) async {
      await setScreenSizeForTest(tester: tester);
      app.main();
      await tester.pumpAndSettle();

      expect(find.text('Contact'), findsOneWidget);
})}


better add Your dart code to Your question. I think server that spinned up in test is blocking execution
